# How to implement Treelist dropdown in Xamarin?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.forms

I want to implement something like below in the Xamarin forms.

I don't see such implementation with Objective C so can't find a way to render it through Native either.

How do I implement this with Xamarin forms?

https://demo.mobiscroll.com/javascript/list/display#

[image]

Comment: Looks like a UIPickerView. This [tutorial is a bit dated, but should put you on the right track](https://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2017/11/create-multiple-component-uipickerview-ios-swift-tutorial.html). Or [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926570/using-uipickerview-with-multiple-components-in-swift), which is a bit more condensed

Comment: If in Xmarin.ios, you can custom `PickerRenderer` to do .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/picker#working-with-a-picker-control

Answer (score 1):

Working Solution: what follows will get your two-column UIPickerView rendered from Xamarin.Forms, belatedly updated from my original post

#### Option 1: Custom Renderer

I used the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/picker#working-with-a-picker-control) [@Junior Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10504796/junior-jiang-msft) shared in comments to inspire a quick Custom Renderer that should suit your needs.

First, make a placeholder control in your shared/Xamarin.Forms project:

```cs
namespace samples.core.Controls
{
    public class MultiPickerControl : Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout
    {
        public MultiPickerControl()
        {
            // Just a placeholder
        }
    }
}
```

Then, make the renderer in your iOS project:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(samples.core.Controls.MultiPickerControl), typeof(samples.iOS.Controls.Picker.MultiPickerRenderer))]
namespace samples.iOS.Controls.Picker
{
    public class MultiPickerRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        static UIPickerView pickerControl;
        static DemoModel pickerModel = new DemoModel(new UILabel());

        public MultiPickerRenderer()
        {
            pickerControl = new UIPickerView(
                new CGRect(
                    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.X - UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width,
                    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 230,
                    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width,
                    180))
            {
                Model = pickerModel
            };
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.Add(pickerControl);
            }

            if(e.NewElement != null)
            {
                (e.NewElement as StackLayout).Children.Add(pickerControl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also need a `UIPickerViewModel` to give to your picker. This example is derived from the documentation above:

```cs
    public class DemoModel : UIPickerViewModel
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> options = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            { "America", new string[] { "Mexico", "USA" } },
            { "Europe", new string[] { "Germany", "France", "Italy"} },
            { "Asia", new string[] { "Korea", "Japan"} },
        };

        public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView) => 2; // This determines how many columns are rendered
        public override nfloat GetComponentWidth(UIPickerView picker, nint component) => component == 0 ? 120f : 160f;
        public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView picker, nint component) => 40f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the number of rows to render in a component
        /// </summary>
        public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0)
                return options.Keys.Count;
            else
            {
                var driver = pickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(0);
                return options.Values.ElementAt((int)driver).Length;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the display value for a row in a component
        /// </summary>
        public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0)
                return options.Keys.ElementAt((int)row);
            else
            {
                var driver = pickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(0);
                return options.Values.ElementAt((int)driver).ElementAt((int)row);
            }
        }

        [Export("pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:")]
        public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            // Update the display for column 2 if the value of column 1 has changed
            if (component == 0)
            {
                pickerView.ReloadComponent(1);
                pickerView.Select(0, 1, false);
            }
        }
```

Lastly, reference your placeholder control in the markup (or code behind). Xamarin will resolve the platform implementation when your code is run.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:samples.core.Controls;assembly=samples.core"
             x:Class="samples.core.Views.EntryMoveNextView" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:samples.core.Controls;assembly=samples.core">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="15,25">
            <controls:MultiPickerControl x:Name="MultiPicker"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The result should look like this:

[image: Product Demo]

Be sure to hook into the events available
I've added the above example to a [samples repo on my GitHub](https://github.com/JoeM-RP/xamarin-samples), if you'd like to browse as a unified source.

#### Option 2: Native View

You also might be able to accomplish this with a Native View ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml#subclassing-native-views)). The gist would look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:UIKit;assembly=Xamarin.iOS;targetPlatform=iOS"
             x:Class="samples.core.Views.EntryMoveNextView" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:samples.core.Controls;assembly=samples.core">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="15,25">
            <ios:UIPickerView>
                <!-- Manipulate UIPickerView Properties Here -->
            </ios:UIPickerView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

As with the linked documentation above, be sure to set `GetComponentCount` in your `UIPickerViewModel` to indicate how many columns you'll show.

Good luck!